# C++ remove empty lines from cin and save to same file

Tags: c++

A part of my assignment is to make a program that reads a file that is passed from command line like this: `inputfile.cpp | ./pg_rmv_empty_lines`.
This (I guess) is for that reason that later on I can pipe(?) the same file to multiple programs.

I know I can read lines in that file with:

```
int main()
{
    string line;
    while(getline(cin, line))
    {
        cout << line << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I need to do, is to remove all empty lines in the file that the program receives, remove those lines and then save the modified file.

1. I don't know the name of the file that needs modification, it's passed from the command line by "client"
2. Filename should stay the same after the modifications.

This is confusing me because every example I find, people suggests something that includes hardcoding filename into the source code like `outfile.open("movieList.txt",ios_base::app);`. In my case I don't know the name of the input file.

Bear in mind that I'm using C++ first time and it's already making me lose my faith in humanity.

Comment: The requirement is unclear. The suggestion of piping the output through std::cout seems to conflict with "Filename should stay the same..." Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

To get the filename you need to [parse command line arguments](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/). Once you've done that, examples you referred to will work to read the lines from the file. Assuming file isn't big, you can read it into the memory, skipping the empty lines using `if` statement.

Once you've read the file into memory, you should either close it and re-open for writing or reset to the beginning and write the buffer out.

If the file is large and couldn't be read into the memory buffer, you only can pull this out by doing one line (or limited number of lines) at a time and save the results into a temporary file with a different name. After that you'd have to delete the old file and rename the new file. Of course, the other way (first rename original file and then save new one with the old name) works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the filename from the command line is easy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> // Because why not.

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        return -1; // Indicates error
    }
    std::string filename = argv[1];
    std::ifstream input(filename);

    // Do your stuff...

    return 0;
}
```

No more hints :-)

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that the requirement is to use the pipe command? I think what you want is to use command line arguments. Maybe this article here helps:

http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DEN36Up4/

You can define your main function as:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
...
}
```

and then argc is the amount of commandline arguments were given and argv is the arguments. The first argument is always the name of your program. So if you execute `myprogram.exe ./pg_rmv_empty_lines`, argv[0] would be *myprogram.exe* and argv[1] would be *./pg_rmv_empty_lines*

You can then use this to dynamically read from that file in your code but you first need to open the file. For example something along the lines of:

```
std::ifstream myFile;
std::string lineAsString;
myFile.open(argv[1]);
std::getline(myFile, lineAsString);

... do things with the line

myFile.close();
```